# Create Local apt repo with staging environment

Tags: apt

I am trying to create an apt repository with reprepro which is very straight forward for the most part. I have been using this article as a reference because I liked the structure of having a staging tree.

http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-local-apt-repositories.html

However, I can't seem to wrap my head around what is probably very simple.
Using an example conf/distributions from the article below, I am confused by the fact that when I import a package it always only goes to main. There is no directory called precise-staging and precise-prod? What I am trying to do is have a separate place to put packages that have not been tested and another for production in the same repo.  (/opt/packages/pool/trusty-prod, /opt/packages/pool/trusty-stage)

I could point clients at either of them as needed via /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ with puppet..

Am I completely missing the how this would be done or understanding this article?

```
Dailymotion Precise packages (staging)
Origin: Dailymotion 
Label: dm-staging   
Suite: precise-staging
Codename: precise-staging
Architectures: i386 amd64 source
Components: main role/dns role/database role/web # ➊
Description: Dailymotion Precise staging repository
Contents: .gz .bz2
Tracking: keep
SignWith: yes
NotAutomatic: yes # ➋
Log: packages.dm-precise-staging.log
 --type=dsc email-changes

Dailymotion Precise packages (prod)
Origin: Dailymotion # ➌
Label: dm-prod      # ➌
Suite: precise-prod
Codename: precise-prod
Architectures: i386 amd64 source
Components: main role/dns role/database role/web # ➊
Description: Dailymotion Precise prod repository
Contents: .gz .bz2
Tracking: keep
SignWith: yes
Log: packages.dm-precise-prod.log
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 steps to setting up a simple repository for yourself

1.Install dpkg-dev
2.Put the packages in a directory
3.Create a script that will scan the packages and create a file apt-get update can read
4. Add a line to your sources.list pointing at your repository

Install dpkg-dev

Type in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
```

The Directory

Create a directory where you will keep your packages. For this example, we'll use

```
 /usr/local/mydebs.  


sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/mydebs
```

Now move your packages into the directory you've just created.

Previously downloaded Packages are generally stored on your system in the /var/cache/apt/archives directory. If you have installed apt-cacher you will have additional packages stored in its /packages directory.

The Script update-mydebs

It's a simple three liner:

```
#! /bin/bash
 cd /usr/local/mydebs
 dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -9c > Packages.gz
```

Cut and paste the above into gedit, and save it as update-mydebs in ~/bin. (the tilde '~' means your home directory. If ~/bin does not exist, create it: Ubuntu will put that directory in your PATH. It's a good place to put personal scripts). Next, make the script executable:

```
 chmod u+x ~/bin/update-mydebs
```

How the script works:
dpkg-scanpackages looks at all the packages in mydebs, and the output is compressed and written to a file (Packages.gz) that apt-get update can read (see below for a reference that explains this in excruciating detail). /dev/null is an empty file; it is a substitute for an override file which holds some additional information about the packages, which in this case is not really needed. See deb-override(5) if you want to know about it.

Sources.list

add the line

```
deb file:/usr/local/mydebs ./
```

to your /etc/apt/sources.list, and you're done.

CD Option

You can burn the directory containing the debs to a CD and use that as a repository as well (good for sharing between computers). To use the CD as a repository, simply run

```
sudo apt-cdrom add
```

Using the Repository

Whenever you put a new deb in the mydebs directory, run

```
sudo update-mydebs
sudo apt-get update
```

Now your local packages can be manipulated with Synaptic, aptitude and the apt commands: apt-get, apt-cache, etc. When you attempt to apt-get install, any dependencies will be resolved for you, as long as they can be met.

Badly made packages will probably fail, but you won't have endured dpkg hell.

Comment: Yeah I know there are several ways to create a local repo but is my understanding of what you can do with the Components paramter in conf/distributions wrong? I need to have a seperate repo for packages that are in staging than what is in production. SO what I want to do is be able to is something like deb http://packages.dm.gg/dailymotion precise-prod prod and deb http://packages.dm.gg/dailymotion precise-prod stage. Is this not possible without a completely different design.

Comment: a better question to clarify is this. What does these Components allow me to do: Components: main trusty-prod? How would I configure a client to allow pull from trusty-prod or maybe trusty-stage?